# Transmission knocking and coolant bubbling?

Tags: ford, transmission, overheating, explorer

My 92 Ford Explorer knocks a bit when I switch gears. No matter what gear I switch to... (park to drive, drive to reverse, drive to neutral, neutral to park, it doesn't matter)... the car just rocks a bit forward just one jolt. What is this?

Also... after long drives (like 25 miles), when I shut off the car, I can hear a bit of bubbling coming from the coolant/wiper fluid reservoir. Is this bad?

Thanks!

Comment: if its a coolant reservoir check your oil dipstick , does it look normal? , or looks whitish

Answer (score 2):

> My 92 Ford Explorer knocks a bit when I switch gears.

Check your u-joints. Park the Explorer with the emergency brake on, leaving it in neutral (flat ground, please). Crawl under your vehicle and grab the drive shaft and turn it to see if there is any movement difference or makes any noise. Also, push it in different directions (up/dow) to see if there is movement or noise. If there is a problem there, you should be able to detect movement.

> When I shut off the car, I can hear a bit of bubbling coming from the coolant/wiper fluid reservoir.

These are two very different places on your vehicle. One (the wiper fluid reservoir) will not have anything happening to it as described (no way for this to happen). Which leaves us at the coolant overflow reservoir.

Have you *actually* witnessed it happening, or are you just hearing noise and assuming that's what you are hearing? If you are assuming, I'd state what you are hearing is more than likely the gurgling noise of an AC unit, which would be perfectly normal.

If you have actually witnessed the overflow gurgling, you may have weak radiator cap which is not holding the pressure like it should.

Comment: Hiya Paulster!

On my '92, the coolant overflow reservoir has a tank for the windshield wiper fluid connected to it. They are like 1 unit so I just figured I'd state them both together. My bad for the confusion.

I did witness it happening. It was only after a long drive on a hot day.. I turned off the car and I was chatting with my girlfriend. We both heard that weird bubbling sound. I got out and popped the hood. It was most certainly coming from the overflow tank. It must have gotten so hot that it was actually BOILING the coolant? 

I went to purchase a new radcap and.. (to be continued)

Comment: the guy at the auto parts store told me to check for residue around the radcap neck... he said if there's no residue.. there's probably no need for a new radcap?

He said if the radcap was bad, there would probably be some white residue around the old radcap? Is this true?

And just to make sure: If there is ANY MOVEMENT AT ALL in the drive shaft, that's the problem, right?! How would I correct that movement? Tightening it...or??